# Malware abusing SSH agent active keys

Tags: malware, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, key

I am thinking about this lately a lot, so I wanted to get someone else's opinion.

Let's say that I have an SSH key agent (e.g. Pageant or `ssh-agent`) running in background with loaded keys (keys were, of course, passphrase-protected). What stops a malware (running as a current user) from exploiting this, connecting to a SSH host and possibly running remote commands?

I hope that my understanding of this is flawed but, as long as agent is running in background, I can issue an `ssh` command and go right through the login.

Can you please help me confirm whether this is correct?

If this is in fact valid attack vector, what would be the best a way of protecting myself from it?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the “Security issues” section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent

Comment: Aha, thanks Steve! This clarifies everything! :) Can you please add it as answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Steve](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/99802/steve) helped answering, but this question was still marked unanswered, so:

[WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) says:

> ssh-agent creates a socket and then checks the connections from ssh.
> Everyone who is able to connect to this socket also has access to the
> ssh-agent. The permissions are set as in a usual Linux or Unix system.
> When the agent starts, it creates a new directory in /tmp with
> restrictive permissions. The socket is located in this directory.
>
> There is a procedure that may prevent malware from using the ssh-agent
> socket. If the ssh-add -c option is set when the keys are imported
> into the ssh-agent, then the agent requests a confirmation from the
> user using the program specified by the SSH_ASKPASS environment
> variable, whenever ssh tries to connect.
>
> Ssh-agents can be "forwarded" onto a server you connect to, making
> their keys available there as well, for other connections. On the
> local system, it is important that the root user is trustworthy,
> because the root user can, amongst other things, just read the key
> file directly. On the remote system, if the ssh-agent connection is
> forwarded, it is also important that the root user on the other end is
> trustworthy, because it can access the agent socket on the remote
> (though not the key, which stays local).